# Horizontal scroll bar doesn't work on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; width: 150px; height: 100px; display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <select multiple name="" id="" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
        <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It works well on Chrome, but horizontal scroll bar doesn't work on Firefox, is there any way to fix the problem?
[image]

Chrome
[image]
Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: flex;`. Use `overflow-y: scroll;` if you want to see the vertical scrollbar w/out scrolling right.

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; width: 150px; height: 100px; 
            overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;">
  <select multiple name="" id="">
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
    <option value="">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
  </select>
</div>
```